# Remote access via GUI

Tags: windows, gui, remote-access

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine that I currently access using SSH. I'd like to know if there's a way to remotely access via GUI from a Windows OS, because I would like to access my Ubuntu box when I'm away from my house.
I did a little research before posting this, but I haven't found anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a VNC server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server)

Comment: Freenx is faster and more secure then any other VNC server. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX If it is a server I highly advise a web solution such as webmin

Comment: Thank you guys very much. I'm testing xrdp now and everything is doing good for now.