# Is there a LiveCD that contains TeamViewer that works out-of-the-box? If not, how can I generate one?

Tags: live-cd, vnc, remote, teamviewer

Is there a Ubuntu distribution that comes with TeamViewer (or similar VNC based service) that is as foolproof as possible?

Comment: "that is as foolproof as possible?" is a matter of opinion. And do you mean a client or a full working vpn server? Remmina is  the default RDP client and works very well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a VNC/RDP server that would allow me to log in from outside and help fix some problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no LiveUSB/LiveCD or distribution of Ubuntu that comes with TeamViewer builtin.  TeamViewer is third-party closed source software that is packaged by their development teams for Ubuntu - it is not included in the repositories.

It is possible under every Ubuntu distribution to set up `x11vnc` or similar, however, to do VNC functionality that you can access with a VNC viewer.  You may refer to ["How do I install a VNC server?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server) for further guidance on setting up `x11vnc` or other solutions on an Ubuntu system.  (There are not, however, LiveUSBs/LiveCDs of Ubuntu which ship with this - you would have to install them after the fact)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a live ubuntu (kubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu/neon)..... usb with persistence file and install teamviewer (and other desired software) on it. [howto :)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)
If needed you can store a binary image of that disk and create a usb when needed.