# Remmina connect from Ubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I am using Remmina (via snap, so it's the latest) to connect from my Ubuntu 17.04 desktop server to an Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome 3 work server running in VMWare Workstation (on Windows 10). I am able to connect from Ubuntu 17.04 to my Windows 10 laptop using Remmina RDP. I want to connect from my Ubuntu 17.04 desktop server to my Ubuntu 16.04 work server using Remmina.

Can someone please help me accomplish this?

In my Ubuntu 17, I create a new Remmina Remote Desktop Client, pointing it to my Ubuntu 16 (192.168.123.456 on my network) with port 5900 (129.168.123.456:5900) using VNC (Virtual Network Computing) option in Remmina. I provide a user name and a password.

On my Ubuntu 16 work server (where I want to connect into), I start vino-server, and it says it is listening on IPv6://[::]:5900 and IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900. Ifconfig tells me the IP of this VM is 192.168.123.456, which is why I am trying to connect to that from my Ubuntu 17 server.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this forum post:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177810

Basically you need to install a VNC server on your Ubuntu Server

I followed this forum post to setup my VNC server:
[How do I install a VNC server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server)

Hope it helps =)