# How do I change the primary monitor through terminal? (Xubuntu 17.04)

Tags: command-line, monitor

So I have a laptop with a broken screen (cant see anything on it) and I am trying to set a VGA monitor as the primary, but I kind of can't do that very easily when the display settings window opens on the broken laptop screen that I can't see. Is there any way I can fix it in terminal? I've tried deleting monitors.xml, and even setting VGA1 to primary in xrandr, but for some reason that didn't even work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a vnc server on the host and connect from another computer or tablet on the network with a vnc client

I like this one the second answer has full terminal commands for configuring too.

[How do I install a VNC server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server)

After that get a vnc client on a tablet or another PC  to connect to your host and change your monitor setting to duplicate/clone your screen not extend.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's okay I managed to fix it, I just set VGA1 to primary in xrandr and then told xrandr to place the VGA1 monitor on the other side of the laptop monitor and it fixed it.

Comment: How did you do this?