# How To Install VNC Server On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: remote-desktop, file-sharing, remote, remote-access

How To Install VNC Server On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ...

How to access  Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10  using Remote Acess ...

Answer (score -2):

## Install tightvncserver.

```
apt-get -y install tightvncserver
```

## Login with a user you'd like to set VNC. By the way, this example shows to use Xfce Desktop on VNC.

## set VNC password

```
vncpasswd
```

## Password:

## Verify:

## start VNC server

```
tightvncserver :1
```

## New 'dlp:1 (ubuntu)' desktop is dlp:1

## Creating default startup script /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup

## Starting applications specified in /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup

## Log file is /home/ubuntu/.vnc/dlp:1.log

```
tightvncserver -kill :1
```

## stop once

## Killing Xvnc4 process ID 2675

nano ~/.vnc/xstartup

```
exec xfce4-session &
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

> tightvncserver -geometry 1366x768 :1

Comment: this is vncserver but my steps are with tightvnc

Comment: because it was in my database, and I sent it to use this user

Comment: I voted to delete this answer.  If you want, you can post an additional answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168878/how-do-i-install-a-vnc-server) after reading the existing answers and if yours would add any value there.  **;-)**

Comment: that is using xfce